# Match CSR to Apple Pay certificate

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle, x509, x509certificate2

I am having difficulty figuring out how to match a certificate to a csr. On my end, I create the CSR using Pkcs10CertificationRequest where I  create a curve cryptography (ECC) key pair by using   the following

```
        DerObjectIdentifier ecParam = new DerObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.10045.3.1.7");
        ECKeyPairGenerator keyGen = new ECKeyPairGenerator();
        keyGen.Init(new ECKeyGenerationParameters(ecParam, new SecureRandom()));
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPairServer = keyGen.GenerateKeyPair();
```

.  I save off the private and public key for later user. Once I upload the CSR to the Apple pay developer account, i get back a cer. I turn the certificate back into an X509Certificate2 and retrieve the private and public key, but these do not match. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: You only provide the code for key generation, but all your problems seem to be in the code that performs the steps outlined in your last paragraph. Show that code too. Also, please define in more specific detail what you mean by "match".

Comment: Please post the code that does `I turn the certificate back into an X509Certificate2 and retrieve the private and public key`